# ssrs - custom printing of subreports

Tags: sql-server, printing, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I am trying to print an ssrs report and the requirement is such that printing of the sub-reports will be performed after printing all the rows of the original report.

what is happening , is that when the ssrs reaches a sub-report it is printing it right the way  and then it is continuing by printing the remaining main report rows.which is the default way.

what we need is when the ssrs reaches a sub-report , it  should continue printing the main report rows and when it finishes it will print the sub-reports.

thank you for your help.